# setting up image server on IIS7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

UPDATE: Somehow the whole thing is now working. I am not sure what did it, but as I was trying new things it all ended up working. Unfortunately none of the answers below were used.

Thanks!

I have set up a Windows 2008 R2 machine (external ip of 123.456.789.012) as an image server. When I type http://123.456.789.012/myImage.jpg in a browser I get a blank page. What am I missing?

Here are the details:

1. The file at : C:\All\ImageServer\myImage.jpg   exists.
2. ImageServer directory security settings:

[image]

3. IIS Advanced Setting:[image]
4. App Pool:

[image]

5. I also have "Web Server -> Common Http Features -> Static Content" role turned on:

[image]

However I did this after installing IIS, and while I have rebooted, the problem persists.

Comment: When you get the blank page, do you get an http status with it? Do your requests show up in the http logs? If so, what's the http status and sub status? Have you monitored the file with Process Monitor?

Comment: Thanks! The logs have http status of 200:

2015-02-04 20:39:57 98.210.153.164 I1\Administrator 123.456.789.012 21 NOOP - 200 0 0 5adecd1b-a0d4-4633-8fc0-641e74735fff -
2015-02-04 20:40:57 98.210.153.164 I1\Administrator 123.456.789.012 21 NOOP - 200 0 0 5adecd1b-a0d4-4633-8fc0-641e74735fff -
2015-02-04 20:41:57 98.210.153.164 I1\Administrator 123.456.789.012 21 NOOP - 200 0 0 5adecd1b-a0d4-4633-8fc0-641e74735fff -
2015-02-04 20:42:57 98.210.153.164 I1\Administrator 123.456.789.012 21 NOOP - 200 0 0 5adecd1b-a0d4-4633-8fc0-641e74735fff -

Comment: These look like FTP logs to me not http. What http status does the browser show (F12 tools, network tab)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try adding IIS_IUSRS to the Security permissions with Read access.

Also check the Mime Types to make sure the .jpg entry is there with a MIME Type of image/jpeg.

Comment: Thanks! I added IIS_IUSRS and there was no change. The MIME type of image/jpeg was also already there.

Comment: What happens if you create a "default.htm" file in the root of the site with the text "Hello" in it? Will it render the text?

Comment: No it doesn't. It shows a blank page.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, it renders it fine. http://localhost/default.htm will display the file: C:\All\ImageServer\Default.htm

Comment: What account is the AppPool "ImageServer" running as? Should be under Advanced Settings -> Process Model -> Identity. I think this defaults to NetworkService. If that's not what it is, maybe temporary switch it to run under NetworkService, recycle the app pool and try again as a troubleshooting step?

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

Change the default virtual folder to : c:\inetput\wwwroot\ImageServer\
so move the ImageServer folder into wwwroot

Check the "binding" pane in the IIS server option that shows this way

Type: http

IP Address: All Unassigned

Port: 80

Host Name: Empty

Solution 2:
Add "ANONYMOUS LOGON" user with all related read and execute permisions

if this doesn't work. check all parent folder: C:\inetput\wwwroot users and inherit of permisions and any folder in there, they have the correct permisions.

I'd recomend solution 1 will work.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment...
What do you get when try directly on the server itself: http://localhost/myImage.jpg

Hope this helps!